# Type providers (Web3Provider) does not exist on ethers

Tags: ethers.js

Can anyone answer how to access `Web3Provider` from ethers?

**Code:**

```
import {ethers} from 'ethers';

const { ethereum } = window as any;

const getEthereumContract = () => {

    const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(ethereum);
    const signer = provider.getSigner();
    const { Contract } = ethers;

    const contract = new Contract(contractAddress, contractABI, signer);

    console.log({
        provider,
        signer,
        contract
    })    
}
```

**Error:**

```
[{
    "resource": "/home/yana/Desktop/projects/crypto/client/src/context/TransactionContext.tsx",
    "owner": "typescript",
    "code": "2339",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Property 'providers' does not exist on type 'typeof import(\"/home/yana/Desktop/projects/crypto/client/node_modules/ethers/lib.esm/ethers\")'.",
    "source": "ts",
    "startLineNumber": 14,
    "startColumn": 33,
    "endLineNumber": 14,
    "endColumn": 42
}]
```

The reason is providers doesn't exits on ethers.
I am unable to locate the reason as everywhere I had searched the code is right.
Also I want to inform I am using **TypeScript** for my project but the things should work the same way as in **JavaScript**

Comment: Yana, can you share the full code of the file?

Comment: Does this helo you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75864189/16139934?

Comment: Yes, it did thanks

Comment: @MilaA or Yana, feel free to post the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `ethers` v6 there are some changes. You can not use `Web3Provider` in version 6, if you want to use `Web3Provider` you have to use version 5 of `ethers` library.
And if you want to stick to the `version 6` of ethers then you can use `ethers.BrowserProvider`.
For e.g.

```js
const { ethereum } = window as any;
const provider = new ethers.BrowserProvider(ethereum);
```

For more information you can check [ethers v6 docs](https://docs.ethers.org/v6/getting-started/)